Problem with downloading PostgreSQL for my java project. It says error about environment variable COMPSEC, etc. please help for my project
I downloaded the latest PostgreSQL from the official page, i allow it to make changes in my computer, then after it loads the postgresql small rectangular startup it shows an error that says "The environment variable COMPSEC does not seem to point to the cmd.exe or thre is a training semicolon present. Please fill this variable and restart installation." please help, i have a project due in five days
i cant find any solutions on the internet. can someone help?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
